Redis restore from backed-up dump.rdb and resetting expiry
We use redis to hold http session data and when in normal operation the session data expires after 30 minutes.
I would like to snapshot the dump.rdb as a way of saving a session so it can be retrieved at anypoint in the future to speed-up development.
The problem I’m encountering is that the expiry is stored as a date and when that elapses I can no longer retrieve it, which gives me 30 minute window only.
Is there a way to modify the expiry in the dump.rdb to allow this? I want to avoid changing the data expiry in the running application.
